# Javascript: Horizontally flip an image object and save it into a new image object

Tags: javascript, sprite

I've created an arrow sprite displayed on a canvas element, initially it points to the right and it moves to the right. When it starts moving to the left I want to rotate this sprite.

Im using multiple sprites so flipping the entire canvas is not really an option.

I could of course create two seperate sprites, but ideally I think it would be better if I rotate the sprite at the start and save it into a new Image object. is this possible? and how should I do this?

P.S. Javascript only, no jQuery.

```
var imagetest = new Image();
imagetest.src = "./img/arrow.png";
```

Comment: Can't you just create a new image object with the same URL and apply a CSS3 transform to it to flip it?

Comment: The thing is i'm creating an image object using javascript, it won't  be placed in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the target either to an existing IMG tag or some JS Image object :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function flip(src,target){
 var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function(){
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width = this.width;
  c.height = this.height;
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  ctx.scale(-1,1);
  ctx.drawImage(this,-this.width,0);
  this.onload = undefined; 
  target.src = c.toDataURL();
 }
 img.src = src;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="flip('SOMESPRITE.PNG',document.getElementById('fliptest'));">
<img id="fliptest" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if I want to change an existing image (already on the DOM), without creating a new one?

Comment: Late, I know - but that's even simpler. For example, you can add these two to its css class or use JS to change it at any point, ie.: **image.style="transform-origin: 50% 0px 0px;transform: rotateY(180deg);"** - the first is the transformation pivot, point where you hold something as you rotate it, the other rotates around Y axis. So you hold image at the top and in the middle, then rotate around Y axis that goes vertically through the middle. 90 degrees would make the image disappear as its side faces the display and 180 is a half turn where the image is flipped.